# How do I access a JavaScript object using another object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the properties of `easeSegmentNameMap` using:

```
easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"].text
```

I'm getting `undefined`, it works if I use:

```
easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"].name

var easeSegmentNameMap = {
  "EMAIL_ENGAGED": {
    name: "emailEngaged"
  },
  "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
    name: "emailInactive"
  },
  "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
    name: "likelyToThrive"
  },
  "MOST_VALUABLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
    name: "mostValuableSubscribers"
  },
  "NEARLY_INACTIVE": {
    name: "nearlyInActive"
  },
  "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
    name: "neverActivated"
  },
  "QUESTION_MARKS": {
    name: "questionMarks"
  }
};

var text = "name";
alert(easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"].text);
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: no `text`, just `name`. why do you want to take `text`?

Comment: There's no property on the objects with the key "text". There is only a single property, and it has the key "name".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert(easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"][text]);
```

`text` is a variable and has to be interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access

```
var text="name";
alert(easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"].text);
```

the **text** is still the property, in this case, it's not the variable. 
If you wanted to access the variable you should access like this:

```
alert(easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"][text]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use `[]` bracket notation. whenever you need to access any object property using variable you need to use `[]` notation.

```js
var easeSegmentNameMap = {
  "EMAIL_ENGAGED": {
    name: "emailEngaged"
  },
  "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
    name: "emailInactive"
  },
  "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
    name: "likelyToThrive"
  },
  "MOST_VALUABLE_SUBSCRIBERS": {
    name: "mostValuableSubscribers"
  },
  "NEARLY_INACTIVE": {
    name: "nearlyInActive"
  },
  "NEVER_ACTIVATED": {
    name: "neverActivated"
  },
  "QUESTION_MARKS": {
    name: "questionMarks"
  }
};

var text = "name";
console.log(easeSegmentNameMap["EMAIL_ENGAGED"][text]);
```